# IMPORTXML to import tooltips to Google Sheet

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, tooltip, google-sheets-formula

Looking to use IMPORTXML in Google Sheets to pull a list of courses available per county from this map https://www.quicktraining.ie/, this data is currently only available as a tooltip for each county, is it possible to import tooltip via IMPORTXML?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
={"Galway", COUNTA(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.quicktraining.ie/county/index.php?county=Galway", 
 "//div[@class='divVanueRow']"))}
```

[image: 0]